# Wine: How to download a file from CMD?

Tags: linux, batch-file, download, wget, wine

Similar to how people basically brought the whole `bash` environment to Windows for various reasons and play with `bash` there, I'd like to do something similar in a very small scale. I noticed there's `cmd.exe`, which allows me to launch `.bat` files. There's just one hitch that stands in my way (batch is a way simpler than bash) and that's an access to the internet.

Obviously, I can compile some C code on Win and copy it to download a file (should be possible from wine), but I want to use **already existing tools in the system**. So, what I ***don't*** have:

- `bitsadmin.exe`
- `powershell`

What I have:

- `wine-1.6.2`
- whole bash environment (wget would be enough if it worked)
- Wine's `iexplore.exe`
- Wine's `cscript.exe`

What I tried:

- `set PATH=%PATH%;Z:\usr\bin && wget` can't recognize a command `wget`, so apparently I can't use such binaries this way although `dir Z:\usr\bin` works fine
- bitsadmin and powershell, missing
- iexplore.exe, no command line support

I also tried VBS from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973344/5994041) answer, but surprisingly it returns some kind of parsing error, which is even ["Unspecified Error"](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_80004005.htm), which is some kind of permission error:

```
Z:\home\hop>cscript test.vbs
Z:\home\hop>fixme:cscript:wWinMain (0x7ed90000 (nil) L"test.vbs" 1) forwarding t
o wscript
fixme:vbscript:VBScript_SetScriptState unimplemented SCRIPTSTATE_INITIALIZED
fixme:vbscript:parse_script parser failed around L"nt\r\n\r\nwith bStrm\r\n\t.ty
pe = 1......
fixme:wscript:run_script ParseScriptText failed: 80004005
```

But for some reason `wscript` and `cscript` seem empty:

```
cscript /?
Z:\home\hop>fixme:cscript:wWinMain (0x7ed90000) (nil) L"/?" 1) forwarding to wscript

wscript /?
^ outputs nothing, just an empty newline
```

Those on Windows output either something in console, or a new window with something. I expected at least `cscript` to work.

So... any ideas how to download a (*any*) file from `wine cmd` environment on GNU/Linux distros through console (no clicking, or manually downloading through browser)?

Comment: cygwin provides wget, curl, other unix tools for windows.  have you looked into installing cygwin in wine?

Comment: @quixotic Well, this still remains as the last option which _might_ work, but I'd rather see some more sane way, as I've most likely only missed something.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr 
I post this in comments because, you noticed that you don't have powershell on your system, but anyway perhaps this can help other members and give them some new ideas
 [Download a file from a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017702/download-a-file-from-a-batch-file?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People on #winehq IRC channel (freenode) pointed me to the [docs](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_launch_native_applications_from_a_Windows_application.3F) and I made a tiny wrapper for the `/usr/bin/wget` that's usable and can be a substitute for `bitsadmin.exe` in the GNU/Linux environment.

**Syntax:** `wget.exe switch task_name url filename`, like in bitsadmin:

> bitsadmin /transfer "Task Name" "https://xyz.blob/file.ext" "myfile.ext"

**wget.exe**:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -O $4 $3
```

after that you have to make the file ***executable*** (`chmod +x wget.exe`) which is the only step that pretty much requires user's interaction (would be too good if you could `chmod` silently) after that you can happily use `/usr/bin/wget` like this:

```
wine cmd /c wget.exe /transfer "Task Name" "https://xyz.blob/file.ext" "myfile.ext"
```

**Note:** The joke is that Wine doesn't require a file to be Windows executable to actually run it, that's why it's capable of running a bash script this way if it's set as an executable and if you can access bash you know how to continue...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Hybrid script **[Batch/Vbscript]** to download a file !

```bat
@echo off
mode con:cols=90 lines=10
title -==*==- Batch File Downloader -==*==-
(
echo Option Explicit
echo.
echo Dim Message, result
echo Dim Title, Text1, Text2
echo.
echo Message = "Type the URL of the file to download http://www.kcc.edu/campaigns/PublishingImages/poh.jpg"
echo Title = "Type the URL of the file to download"
echo Text1 = "You canceled"
echo.
echo result = InputBox^(Message, Title, "http://www.kcc.edu/campaigns/PublishingImages/poh.jpg", 900, 900^)
echo.
echo.
echo If result = "" Then
echo    WScript.Echo Text1
echo Else
echo    WScript.Echo result
echo End If
)>"%tmp%\inputbox.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=*" %%a in ('Cscript "%tmp%\inputbox.vbs" //nologo') do (set "a=%%a")
(
echo path = "%A%"
echo pos = InStrRev(path, "/"^) +1
echo Const DownloadDest = "%A%"
echo LocalFile = Mid(path, pos^)
echo Const webUser = "admin"
echo Const webPass = "admin"
echo Const DownloadType = "binary"
echo dim strURL
echo.
echo function getit(^)
echo  dim xmlhttp
echo.
echo  set xmlhttp=createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0"^)
echo  'xmlhttp.SetOption 2, 13056 'If https -^) Ignore all SSL errors
echo  strURL = DownloadDest
echo  Wscript.Echo "Download-URL: " ^& strURL
echo.
echo  'For basic authentication, use the list below, plus user variables? Give Way
echo  xmlhttp.Open "GET", strURL, false, WebUser, WebPass
echo  'xmlhttp.Open "GET", strURL, false
echo.
echo  xmlhttp.Send
echo  Wscript.Echo "Download-Status: " ^& xmlhttp.Status ^& " " ^& xmlhttp.statusText
echo.
echo  If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
echo    Dim objStream
echo    set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream"^)
echo    objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
echo    objStream.Open
echo    objStream.Write xmlhttp.responseBody
echo    objStream.SaveToFile LocalFile , 2 '//overwrite
echo    objStream.Close
echo    set objStream = Nothing
echo  End If
echo.
echo.
echo  set xmlhttp=Nothing
echo End function
echo.
echo getit(^)
echo Wscript.Echo "Download complete. Check " ^& LocalFile ^& " for Success."
echo Wscript.Quit(intOK^)
)>"%tmp%\httpdownload.vbs"
::Start
echo(
echo  Please wait ... Download file is in progress ...
for /f "tokens=* delims=*" %%a in ('Cscript "%tmp%\httpdownload.vbs" //nologo') do (echo "%%a")
Del %tmp%\httpdownload.vbs
::End
pause>nul
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work in Wine as it's the same thing (with unnecessary stuff around) like I used originally i.e. the linked answer in my question. It doesn't work because Wine has some problems with `adodb` even after installing necessary libraries that should make it work.