# How can I download a file from Wine CMD on Fedora?

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, wget, wine

Note: This is simillar to the question here: [Wine: How to download a file from CMD?](https://superuser.com/questions/1192279/wine-how-to-download-a-file-from-cmd) however, I was not able to use or understand the answer provided. I need to be able to donwload a file from within a batch code on linux wine. I have no powershell or cscript. I'd be fine with an exe I could use, and I would love to be able to use wget from within the linux computer. I am running Fedora 25.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a strange but fairly easy workaround. I created a bash script (I had to to start the script anyway) and I made a loop in it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash    
for (( ; ; ))
    do
       echo "Pres CTRL+C to stop..."
       wget File
       wine CMD batchFile.bat
    done
```

Then, when I wanted to download the file in the batch file, I would exit. It would download the file and start again. When I ran into the problem of needing a download in multiple places, I created a text file with all my variables saved like `set Var1=Hello World` and when the batch file first ran it would do this command: `for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (Variables.txt) do %%A`. It isn't ideal but it was the easiest way I could find to do it.